# Facebook comment plugin doesn't work at all

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

I inserted the facebook code where required and absolutely nothing happens or shows up.  Using dreamweaver cs6 and in live view or when testing in ANY browser, nothing shows up.  It's a blank box.  ANy thoughts?   I read somewhere that the website must be made into an application of facebook?  Is this something?

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, after activating the plugin and properly connecting the plugin to the facebook app,which does work and has been used extensively before hand, comments simply fail to load. There is no comment box, no past comments pull in either (note the app has historical comments already).

In the plugin settings area on the right side of the screen where the comments check box exists, there is a read more link that takes you to the facebook developers page where it discusses adding the facebook comments iframe.

If there is some other location where comment settings might also exist (past the three fields that require the 2 keys and the app name) I could not find them and this was not referenced in the plugin setup.